# Start Youtube video via api on click/touch on mobile

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I have the following page where when you click on the button, it plays the video automatically via the youtube api:

http://machinas.com/wip/hugoboss/youtube/

I'm using the following code which loads the video and by setting the playerVars to autoplay, it will begin the video automatically.

```
 $("#container.click-to-play-video").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            width : '960',
            height : '540',
            videoId : 'jXkK2vkGnh8',
            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1 , 'autohide': 1 },
            events : {
                'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    });
```

This works fine on desktop/PC but on mobile it doesn't play the video, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a restriction of the API that only allows playback if it's initiated by the user.

It's explained in detail in the YouTube API reference [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations), but it's essentially to prevent unauthorised data usage over cellular networks.

I suppose you might be able to circumvent via simulating a click event with JS, but from a UX perspective it might be best to get a user to consent to streaming a video over their cellular network first.